# How can I initialize static const class member object referring to private fields?

Tags: c++11, static-members, pointer-to-member, access-specifier

Here's the problem: a class called `Factory` has several non-static member functions of the same signature, let's call them `f1`, `f2` and so on. I'd like to put pointers to these member functions in a `std::vector` that's a `static const`, as there's no need for that to ever change in runtime. Similarly, for reasons of elegance, I don't want to expose `f1` and the others (summarily `fi` below), and not the `vector` either, but that's secondary.

Initializing the `vector` in class *won't work* because it's an incomplete type, and `&Factory::fi` are unknown at that time. Initializing it outside at file level *won't work* because `fi` are private and I can't befriend the global scope. Putting that in an initialization function and making that a `friend` *won't work* because that would require rewriting a `const`.

What works is:

- removing the `static const` qualifiers, at the cost of making an unnecessary copy of this `vector` for each instance.
- writing a `static` member function that declares a `static` variable and returns it. I thought this would be just as good but it makes my program run twice as slow with all optimizations on.

Surely, I would like to see a solution without the latter drawbacks. Please don't advise me to call the functions from a `switch` or similar vast changes of the paradigm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you have in mind? It wasn't quite clear from the problem statement.

```
#include <vector>

class Factory {
private:
    void f1() {}
    void f2() {}
public:
    typedef void (Factory::*PF)();
    static const std::vector<PF> v;
};

const std::vector<Factory::PF> Factory::v{&Factory::f1, &Factory::f2};


int main()
{
    Factory f;
    (f.*Factory::v[0])();
}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/KEJM77890)

Comment: That's one of the approaches that I tried and didn't work (second case in second paragraph of the q). It says "Error: [signature...] Factory::f1() is private within this context". Well, it does not in *your* example. I'll need to find how that differs significantly from my current code.

Comment: And sorry for being unclear, although I fail to see where. Your code is exactly the scenario I have in mind. Strangely this works alone (and is indeed one of the methods I tried first) but produces the above error when within my larger project.

Comment: @TheVee Well, if you'd like further assistance, show [an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the failure. I can't help with code I can't see.

Comment: OMG, I forgot to call it `Factory::v` in the definition. And the compiler was happy about *that* because the class's `v` was then simply left an empty vector, but it thought I was trying to define a new const called `::v`, accessing the private fields. Thanks so much, your code (as a proof this is meant to work) helped me find this stupid error of mine!